# using expect: how to print a message on the screen and not on an opened log file

Tags: expect, logs

I have an *expect* shell, and a log file has to be opened at the beginning, then inside a for loop I want to check certain conditions, if these conditions are met I want to print out a message into the screen and not to a log file

Note:

I have tried to use `send_log`, `send_error`, `send_user` and `puts`, but none of them worked for me. Do I have to close the log_file and then open it every time I want to print something to the screen and not to the log file?

example of the code:

```
log_file -a something.log
.
.
.
for loop { 
log something to the log file
if certain condition met {
 then log to a screen only
}
log_file
```

Answer (score 3):

`puts` seems to ignore the logfile for me (`expect version 5.45` Debian 8):

```
$ > logtest; expect -c 'log_file logtest; send_user "foo\n"; puts bar' 
foo
bar
$ cat logtest
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

in reply to

"puts seems to ignore the logfile for me (expect version 5.45 Debian 8):"

The command from linux shell do it is job, but when you get inside expect shell and open a log file then type puts, this is going to print what you want to print on both the screen and the log file...

i am also using expect version 5.45

Comment: I do not observe that. Also, don't use answers to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mean it...i couldn't comment because my reputation is less than 50.
But really i did the same as what ilkkachu mentioned but inside an expect shell and the result was not as expected:

'code'
$ expect


expect1.1> log_file logtest 


expect1.2> send_user "foo\n"


foo


expect1.3> puts bar


bar


expect1.4> exit


$ cat logtest 


expect1.2> send_user "foo\n"foo


expect1.3> puts barexpect1.4> exit 'code'